# Errors using poshgit from Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, powershell, nuget

I have gotten poshgit to work in plain vanilla powershell with no problems.  When I run a:

```
git pull origin master
```

I get the following good message:

> From github.com:bmccord/WebShot  * branch            master     ->
>   FETCH_HEAD Already up-to-date.

I have also set poshgit up to run form the NuGet Package Manager Console (since it is just a powershell inside of studio).  However, when I run the same command, I get:

> git.cmd : From github.com:bmccord/WebShot At line:1 char:4
>   + git <<<<  pull origin master
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (From github.com:bmccord/WebShot:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError    * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

It looks like it is working, but I also get what looks like an error.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I did.  The answer marked as correct was right.  The console was wrapping the error.  The best way I've found to install git and posh-git on Windows is to use the Github for Windows installer.  Many of my issues went away when I started using that.

Comment: Did installing Github for Windows fix the issue with errors being wrapped in nuget package manager?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I just quit trying to have it setup in the nuget package manager console also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the same message, except that the Package manager console is wrapping the error ( the message that you classify as "good" message, must have been in the standard error)

Comment: Is there a way to stop/alter that behavior? It seems odd that it only shows up in the Package Manager Console and not Powershell normally.

Comment: I too am looking for a way to stop that nasty error wrapping.

Comment: @EricAmodio and AlexFord: you can find some workaround in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12789968/753737) for a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12751261/753737).