# posh git not showing status flags

Tags: git, powershell, posh-git

I got a problem with posh git not showing the status flags.
This is what it looks like:
[image]

As you can see there are changes and my branch is behind the origin, but still the prompt only displays the current branch in Cyan. While it is ahead (Green and should have ~- for modified and deleted files.

i did remove the whole stuff again, and reinstalled it using PsGet Install-Module. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this did not work. The Method Get-GitStatus of GitUtil.ps1 (https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/blob/master/GitUtils.ps1) contains a call to git status that looks like this:

```
$status = git -c color.status=false status --short --branch 2>$null
```

but to make git work in `PowerShell - ISE` i created a git.cmd with the following code:

```
@echo off
git.exe %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 2>&1
```

and added a alias git to target the cmd. As i described here ([Powershell displays some git command results as error in console even though operation was successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751261/powershell-displays-some-git-command-results-as-error-in-console-even-though-ope/33413267#33413267))

Which destroys the git status parsing of the posh~git GitUtils.ps1. I changed the GitUtils.ps1 to

```
$status = git status --short --branch
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same symptoms. They were resolved by upgrading both the [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git), and [oh-my-posh](https://github.com/jandedobbeleer/oh-my-posh) modules, and then restarting my terminal.

See:

- https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git
- https://github.com/jandedobbeleer/oh-my-posh
- https://ohmyposh.dev/

```
PowerShellGet\Update-Module posh-git

Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; Invoke-Expression ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://ohmyposh.dev/install.ps1'))
```